# Insertion error in Filestream enabled table

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, filestream

I use a column in a table to store an apk file as `varchar(max)`.
I converted this existing field in a table that was originally of the type `varchar(max)` to `varbinary(max)` and then made it a `filestream` column to make retrieval faster. However doing this gives me SQL insertion errors in the PHP application logs. The exception message just specifies that there is error in executing insert. I am not sure how this should be handled. What sort of things should be reviewed on the application side when altering a column from `varchar` to `varbinary`?

Comment: Can you include the SQL `INSERT` query in your post? Also, the SQL where you do the `CREATE TABLE` (or `ALTER TABLE`) would be helpful for people trying to answer. The exact error message might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with the FILESTREAM objects using the Windows API calls? See [this MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645940.aspx) for more information on how handling filestream blobs requires Windows API calls.